NET 6 консольное приложение логирование на старте
В Консольном приложении NET 6 не могу писать в лог на старте в файле Program.cs.
Использую NLog
Настройка логгера в файле Program.cs:
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
builder.Host.UseNLog();

using (var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
    using var scope = provider.CreateScope();
    var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBManager>();

    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogInformation("Приложение запущено"); //TODO здесь логгер не работает!!!    
}

В строке:
logger.LogInformation("Приложение запущено");

запись в лог не происходит
Пробовал и другие варианты, к примеру
app.Logger.LogInformation("Test");

тоже не работает.
В данном проекте используется WEb Api, там логгер получаю в конструкторе и он там работает.
Настройка лога в файле appsettings.json:

"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
...

  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246416/nlog-configuration-in-appsettings-json-instead-of-nlog-config-in-net-core
  "NLog": {
    "autoReload": true,
    "throwExceptions": false,
    "internalLogLevel": "Off",
    "internalLogFile": "c:\\temp\\internal-nlog.txt",
    "extensions": [
      { "assembly": "TransactionModule" }
    ],
    "targets": {
      "allfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log",
        "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}",
        "keepFileOpen": true,
        "autoFlush": false,
        "openFileFlushTimeout": "10",
        "openFileCacheTimeout": "10",
        "maxArchiveFiles=": "50",
        "archiveAboveSize": "10000000",
        "archiveEvery": "Monday"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        //удаляем лонирование от EntityFrameworkCore
        "logger": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query",
        "minLevel": "Off",
        "final": true
      },
      {
        "logger": "TransactionModule.*",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "allfile"
      }
    ]
  }
}



А зачем в using блоке?

Нельзя так билдером пользоваться, используйте метод Build(). А BuildServiceProvider - вообще не для вас метод.

Эта строка var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
написана с начале файла. И здесь билдится ServiceProvider
